# compatibility issue of magrittr and arima in R

Tags: r, arima, magrittr

consider the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
forecast::forecast
x <- cumsum(rnorm(10))
y1 <- arima(x, order = c(1, 0, 0))
y2 <- x %>% arima(order = c(1, 0, 0))

length(fitted(y1))
[1] 10
length(fitted(y2))
[1] 0
```

The objects `y1`and `y2`are almost identical, the only exceptions being the slots `call`and `series`. So I guess that is where the `fitted` functions starts its magic.

I would really like to work with `y1` instead of `y2`.
Does anyone know an alternative function to `fitted` which produces the same result?

**EDIT2:**
The above "bug" does not appear if the `forecast` package is not loaded into namespace (via eg. `forecast::forecast`).
I wasnt aware that loading a package into namespace changes the behaviour of some functions.

**EDIT:**
since the code seems not to be reproducible I add my `sessionInfo()´

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.8.0.1   purrr_0.3.0     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_2.0.1    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 magrittr_1.5   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zoo_1.8-4         tidyselect_0.2.5  urca_1.3-0        aTSA_3.1.2        haven_2.0.0       lattice_0.20-38   colorspace_1.4-0  generics_0.0.2    yaml_2.2.0        utf8_1.1.4        rlang_0.3.1       pillar_1.3.1     
[13] withr_2.1.2       glue_1.3.0        forecast_8.5      TTR_0.23-4        modelr_0.1.2      readxl_1.2.0      plyr_1.8.4        quantmod_0.4-13   timeDate_3043.102 munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.2.0      cellranger_1.1.0 
[25] rvest_0.3.2       tseries_0.10-46   lmtest_0.9-36     parallel_3.5.2    curl_3.3          fansi_0.4.0       broom_0.5.1       xts_0.11-2        Rcpp_1.0.0        scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.3   jsonlite_1.6     
[37] fracdiff_1.4-2    hms_0.4.2         stringi_1.3.1     grid_3.5.2        cli_1.0.1         quadprog_1.5-5    tools_3.5.2       lazyeval_0.2.1    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.2   xml2_1.2.0        lubridate_1.7.4
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm also confused; is it possible you are using an `arima` function from a package you haven't mentioned? Because as far as I can tell, there's no `fitted` method for `stats::arima`, and so calling `fitted` on both of those objects returns `NULL`.

Comment: As @joran said, both returns NULL for me as well

Comment: Sorry guys, 
I had the `tidyverse`package loaded but did not think it was relevant for the question. I will edit my question.

Comment: could be that it also loads `forecast`

Comment: I have reproduced the error using stats::arima and stats::fitted

Comment: @akrun, it seems to have something to do with the `forecast` package. 
Although I had not loaded it via `library` I used it like `forecast::...`.
I updated the question again.
Sorry for the misunderstandings.

Comment: I would always use package::function(). Then you are sure what you use.

Comment: @Christoph, 
tried that as well, same behaviour. 
Loading forecast into namespace changes the behaviour of `stats::fitted`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've identified is a problem caused by non-standard evaluation, which is briefly mentioned in [the technical note](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) about the `magrittr` pipe:

> The magrittr pipe operators use non-standard evaluation. They capture
>   their inputs and examines them to figure out how to proceed. First a
>   function is produced from all of the individual right-hand side
>   expressions, and then the result is obtained by applying this function
>   to the left-hand side. For most purposes, one can disregard the subtle
>   aspects of magrittr's evaluation, but some functions may capture their
>   calling environment, and thus using the operators will not be exactly
>   equivalent to the "standard call" without pipe-operators.

If you look at the source for `arima` version of `fitted` you can see that you were correct in thinking that the `call` attribute is essential to the method's operation:

```
getAnywhere(fitted.Arima)
A single object matching ‘fitted.Arima’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for fitted from namespace TSA
  namespace:TSA
with value

function (object, ...) 
{
    fitted = eval(object$call$x) - object$residuals
    fitted
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001e8ff4d8>
<environment: namespace:TSA>
```

Comment: Re "some functions may capture the calling environment", I guess it is `arima` that does this, in its line `series <- deparse(substitute(x))`, while `fitted` just looks up `x` from the capture.

Comment: @Frank The call is captured using the base function `match.call()` and `fitted.Arima` uses that directly. I'm not actually sure what the purpose of saving the "series" is, but perhaps another method somewhere else uses it.